# Inserting Graphics to LyX

Tags: lyx

I need to insert graphics in a lyx document. However, when I do: Insert->Graphics...etc The graphic file is just linked and is not physically in the lyx file. If I need to send the lyx file to someone I need to send the graphic files separately. Is there a way to include the graphics in the lyx file.

I hope I was clear.

Comment: Since this is more of a document preparation question than a programming question, you'll be warmly received at http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep the Lyx document and graphics (or copies of them) in the same directory, and use relative paths when you insert them into your document. When you need to send it, just create an archive (.zip or other) and send that compressed archive.

Answer (score 1):

LyX never links graphics into the .lyx file. Though there is semi-official python script which zip all related material into one archive...